# How can i find values that are one hour away in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I would like to return rides that are one hour away.
For example, if the ride's leavingTime is 19:00 pm and the current time is 18:00 pm it's returned.

```
models.Rides.findAll({
    where: {
      leavingTime: {
        [Op.gt]: // rides whose leaving time is 1 hour or less away
      }
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I've used Sequelize but this is the general idea. Sequelize also supports moment.js which would be even easier.

```
let dt = new Date()
dt.setHours(dt.getHours() - 1)

models.Rides.findAll({
    where: {
      leavingTime: {
        [Op.gt]: dt
      }
    }
  })
```